# Ranorex installation

Tags: c#, ranorex

I have installed ranorex as user1 and while running the automated test I am impersonating user2, 
when i try to use ranorex assemblies for finding the controls I get error with license manager which does not occur if I run the tests with user1.

Since the test require some part to be run as user1 and some part as user2 can I install ranorex in such a way that it is available for all/both the users?

Comment: There is a fine line when licensing questions are off-topic. I think this question should be sent directly to Ranorex. The reason its not a good fit is because: Unlikely we can read the full license, so answers will be speculative, Unlikely to be of value to future visitors
and Likely to need an attorney to interpret what the terms actually mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ranorex licence file is normally installed in **%ProgramData%\Ranorex3_Server.lic** when installed for all users.

Look in the user profile directory of user1 (follow environment variable %USERPROFILE%) for the licence file and copy/move it to the %ProgramData% directory.

If you can't find the licence file, from the Windows start menu, open "Ranorex Licensing" tool as user2 and reconfigure the licence server.

I agree with Jeremy, this is not related to programming but maybe the licence file information can be useful for somebody else.  On our side, we have created scripts to install/upgrade Ranorex on our computers (and to automatically install the licence file). In that case, the information about licence file could be useful to somebody else.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just realized that i forgot to upvote this answer... ☺️